# Select statement returns nothing when column collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in T-sql

Tags: sql-server, collation, string-comparison

I have a select statement as below:

```
SELECT Veri from tblTest 
where  CAST(Veri COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varchar(10))=
 CAST('БHО' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varchar(10))
```

Column `Veri` has collation of type `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.
There is a row with `Veri` equals БHО. However, select statement returns nothing.
Table tblTest's collation is also `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Column definition for column Veri is as follow:

CONDENSED_TYPE: nvarchar(50)
TABLE_SCHEMA: dbo
TABLE_NAME: tblTest
COLUMN_NAME: Veri
ORDINAL_POSITION: 2
COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
IS_NULLABLE: NO
DATA_TYPE: nvarchar
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: 50
CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: 100
NUMERIC_PRECISION:NULL
NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX: NULL
NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL
DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL
CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG: NULL
CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA: NULL
COLLATION_NAME: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CHARACTER_SET_NAME: UNICODE
COLLATION_CATALOG: NULL
DOMAIN_SCHEMA: NULL
DOMAIN_NAME: NULL

Comment: Doesn't Latin1 just include english letters + accented (German, French, Swedish etc.) letters?

Comment: @user1365888, what does this select returns? SELECT CAST(Veri COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varchar(10)) as VeriCol, 
  CAST('БHО' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as varchar(10)) as SomeVal
FROM tblTest

Comment: are there characters replaced with question marks? (from what I know those characters (such as Б) are not actually Latin).

Comment: @EduardUta This select does not return any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T/SQL the string constant `'БHО'` is an ANSI string, and 'Б' is not available so you'll get the question marks that @EduardUta queried. You need to work with Unicode strings, using the N prefix for string constants and nvarchar. Try this;

```
SELECT Veri from tblTest 
where  CAST(Veri COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as nvarchar(10)) =
CAST(N'БHО' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as nvarchar(10))
```

You may be able to remove the COLLATE directives - depends on your schema.

Another thing you can do is to examine a string character by character to see what each character actually is. For example, in your string 'БHО' it might look like the Cyrillic capital letter Be followed by the English letters H and O, but it's not, that's why you are not getting a match.

```
declare @s nvarchar(100) = N'БНО'
declare @i int = 0

while (@i <= len(@s))
begin
    print substring(@s, @i, 1) + N' - 0x' + convert(varchar(8), convert(varbinary(4), unicode(substring(@s, @i, 1))), 2)
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Try typing the Н and О in the string N'БНО' above and running again - you'll see 0x48 and 0x4F respectively.

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: I tried your statement (with and without COLLATE), still no rows returned.

Comment: if I copy 'БНО' from table cell and paste in this sql statement,   
SELECT Veri from tblTest 
where  CAST(Veri COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as nvarchar(10)) =
CAST(N'БНО' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as nvarchar(10))   it works and returns the row. But then in the very same sql statement, if I delete H and then type that H myself then it does not return any rows.

Comment: @user1365888 - that's because the Н is not an H and the О is not an O :) See my edit above for displaying Unicode codes for characters from a string.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But still I don't know how to construct an SQL statement so that I can query my table based on column 'Veri'. I have a search form and need this query to return search results.

Comment: @user1365888 - this is now a very different question. Depending on your application layer (WinForm, web app etc) you will need to investigate inputting Unicode characters to pass to the SQL query. If I've helped you with your SQL I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer.